# ionic cordova run android failed with error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

can't able to run ionic 4 app to device , i have the error during `ionic cordova run android` in ionic 4 as  **Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.**

Error log

```
* What went wrong:
**Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.**
> Android resource linking failed
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
  error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka io.ionic.starter:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
  error: failed linking references.\
```

can't able to build or run ionic 4 app , kindly help me to solve this

[ionic version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL1YH.png)

[npm version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/608Dt.png)

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.7 (C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.2.9

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 7
```

Comment: have you run `ionic serve`? what happens?

Comment: ionic cordova run android , its happening when i install local storage on ionic 4

Comment: Having this issue too. Any solution so far?